# trying to map a css class to an existing element

Tags: html, css

My html cannot be changed, so I need to map a new css stylesheet to the existing elements on the page.

So I have this for a heading:

Existing:

```
<div class="title">Hello</div>
```

My new css for this page, has new css and markup but the html looks like:

```
<h2><span>Hello</span></h2>
```

i need to make the first  snippet look exactly the same as the bottom `<h2>` snippet.

How can I do this w/o changing the html ?

**Update**

My HTML, that I cannot alter, is:

```
<div class=title>Hello</div>
```

I have a new stylesheet that I have to implement, but it has a style , but it only works on:

```
<h2><span>title</span></h2>
```

**So I have to change the behavior of the class title, to mimic the output of what `<h2><span>` does.**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Mediumbean.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, you want `.title` to resemble `h2 span`, and not the other way around. My advice for you is to dowload [Firebug for firefox](http://getfirebug.com/) (assuming you're using firefox) and inspect your `h2` element to see what styles it presently has, and what selectors may already exist for it.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sampsonresume.com](http://sampsonresume.com/labs/firebug.JPG))</sub>

If you don't have firefox, you can get [IEDeveloperToolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) for Internet Explorer, or use Chrome's built-in Element Inspector if you use Chrome. Any option for any browser will do.

Once you have this information, you'll be able to replicate those rules for `.title {  }`.

```
/* According to Firebug for Firefox, we ought to use the following
   rules to mimic our h2 elements */
.title {
  background-image: url(../images/h2bg.png);
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  /* etc */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where you were using

```
div.title {}
```

use

```
h2 > span {}
```

or just

```
h2 {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`h2 span` will work fine if there's nothing else that matches that selector. Make sure you're using a reset style sheet so you don't get any silly styling from the browser for the `<h2>`.

Comment: Yes, every browser can (potentially) style the H2 differently. Don't trust the browser, define `h2` completely for yourself. And then it's trivial to make this match `div .title`

Comment: +1 for the selector suggestion, -1 for the reset stylesheet recommendation. That makes 0.

Comment: @BalusC What's wrong with the reset stylesheet recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

You can even assign both selectors to the same group:

```
.title, h2 span { font-weight: bold; color: #0F0; ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where the new CSS defines the following rule:

```
h2 span { ... }
```

Update it to add the old markup:

```
h2 span, div.title { ... }
```

That will apply all of the styles that are being applied to the span that's inside the h2, to the div.